# How to set tempo in LMMS?

Tags: learning

I use LMMS version 1.0.0. on Ubuntu. According to https://lmms.io/pdf/lmms-manual-0.4.12.pdf "tempo control" is in the toolbar. For me it is default set to 144. I have a open songeditor with content, the vertical bar on the beginning of the song. I can change the tempo, and set this for example to 72. This works. Now I start playing the song in the songeditor. The tempo immediately switches to 144 again, and will play on that speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I created a automation track, and removed it. I went to "tempo", right-click and selected "remove song global automation".

How I found the solution : Further testing was to play each track separate. And changed tempo. All 3 tracks could be played at 72 BPM (tempo).

I saved the project as .mmp file (a XML like file). I search for tempo and found the value 144. In the automationtrack section. I changed this tempo to 72, and saved it. Reloaded the .mmp file. The tempo was 144 BPM. I start playing and the tempo change into 72 and indeed played slowly. I do recall that I created a automationtrack before, and deleted it. So I knew the automation track was there but not visible. I manual deleted the complete automation section in the .mmp file. This did work successful. When I went to change the tempo is saw in the pop-up there was am item "remove song global automation"